# How can I change the type of std::bitset<8> output to an integer without manipulating the original content?

Tags: c++, bitset

I created an array of buffers from .bin file.

```
std::vector<unsigned char> buffer_list(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(file), {});
```

But now I need its binary values like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < buffer_list.size(); i++)
{
    std::bitset<8>(buffer_list[i]);
}
```

Now im stuck here because the `std::bitset<8>(buffer_list[i])` type is `std::bitset<>` but I need to convert it to an integer without changing the original content from `std::bitset<8>(buffer_list[i])`.
I am full aware of
`std::bitset<8>(buffer_list[i]).to_ulong()` but as I said, I don't want to change the original content.

Comment: `to_ulong()` method doesn't change anything, it returns you the content of bitset as integer.

Comment: Also, `unsigned char` is already an integer... What exactly do you want to do? Can you show an example of content in `buffer_list` and what should be the output in the loop?

Comment: @Yksisarvinen the output should be
`11101110
10010000
00011010
10111000
11101110
11100110
01011011
10011111
11101101
01101001
01101011
10100101`

Comment: In this case you want `to_string()` method (and maybe `std::stoi()`), but I'm not sure if you understand the difference between value and number representation. Value "one hundred ninety-two" can be represented as `192` in decimal and `11000000` in binary, but both are the same value. If you go through `std::stoi(bitset<8>(192).to_string())`, you get `11000000` as integer, but that's a decimal representation, so the value is "eleven million".

Comment: Yes, I understand, I need this for CRC32 algorithm

Comment: Thank you @Yksisarvinen , it's working!